# JQuery not receiving the result of a POST request

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-post, concrete5

I appreciate that there are a lot of posts on this particular subject but none seem to address my particular issue.

I'm using jQuery's post method to query a database for a value equal to the text in an input box. The returned result is supposed to be displayed in the text input box below. But for some reason the success condition of the post request is never executing. Logically this suggests that there's an error either in my post request or in the PHP file it's posting to so I shall paste the code of both here.

The jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#title').change(function() {
    var data = 'title='+$(this).val();
    $.post('getinfo.php', data, function(response){
        if(response.toString() == 'invalid')
        {
            alert('no such book title');
        }
        else
        {
            alert('book found');
        }
    });

    return false;      // required to not open the page when form is submited
  });
  });
```

the get info.php file

```
<?php

defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die(_("Access Denied."));

$title = $_post['title'];

      $db = loader::db();
      $res = $db -> Execute('select isbn from btBookList where title = ?', array($title));

        if($res !=null)
        {
            $identifier = '';
            foreach($res as $row)
            {
            $identifier = $row['isbn'];
            }
            echo json_encode($identifier);
        }
        else

            echo 'invalid';
?>
```

This is using concrete 5 hence the `defined('C5_EXECUTE') or die(_("Access Denied."));` and

```
$db = loader::db();
          $res = $db -> Execute('select isbn from btBookList where title = ?', array($title));
```

Comment: you are allowing for sql injection through the title post variable.  I believe your issue is with the data portion of your post.

Comment: Are you accessing your jQuery file locally, or through a web server? (even if it's locally hosted) .. basically, does the URL in your address bar start with 'http', or 'file'? If the latter, you may be encountering a cross domain policy file error (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: What happens when there are no matching rows? Does $res actually become null or is it an empty array?
Have you tried examining the network request/response to/from your getinfo.php page using Chrome, Safari, or Firefox developer tools?

Comment: `var data = {'title' : this.value};`, and it's `$_POST`).

Comment: First: don't worry about the SQL innjection. abc123 is wrong. Second, if someone has solved your problem, mark as an answer so we don't keep trying. Third -- what *IS* being returned? You say the "success condition" isn't. But is "invalid" being returned? relative paths can be tricky, and your getinfo.php file isn't the correct "format" for a normal page, or called at the correct location for a tool.

Answer (score 0):

Pass data in param:

```
var data = {'title' : $(this).val()};
$.post('getinfo.php', data,function(response){
 alert("Success: " + response);
}).fail(function() {
 alert("Failed...");
});
```

Comment: Can query string values be captured from $_POST array?

Comment: I don't know, more i think so. Make a test

Comment: FYI: just got around with it, $_POST array does not consider query string parameters :).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the way you are retrieving the 'posted' data.  Try using `$title = $_POST['title'];` (i.e. `$_POST` all caps) in your `getinfo.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax call is correct. Success condition of the post request is never executing because of some error is occurring in getinfo.php. It may be because of `$_post['title']` it should be `$_POST['title']`. Please check response text in console.